# C# SerialPort can't receive from Arduino Micro

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port

Trying to communicate between .NET Framework 4.6.1 SerialPort and an Arduino Micro, I can successfully send bytes to the Micro but can't receive. Trying an echo test, the Arduino receive works (and RX lights up) but TX fails - no bytes or error sent.  I've stripped the code down as much as possible to where the Arduino simply writes a character every second and the C# app just reads in a loop, but no bytes are received. The Micro TX light doesn't light up and the Serial.write call returns 0. I have turned on/off all the various flow control/handshake settings I can find, makes no difference.  Confirmed Parity/Stop Bits etc.  I can go back and forth between my test app and RealTerm, and everything works with RealTerm just fine, close it and launch the C# SerialPort app and nada. How is it possible for the SerialPort to fail this?

### C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        readPacket();
    }

    private static void readPacket()
    {
        var spd_Port = new SerialPort("COM4", 115200);
        spd_Port.ErrorReceived += Spd_Port_ErrorReceived;
        spd_Port.Open();

        while (true)
        {
            while (spd_Port.BytesToRead > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(spd_Port.ReadChar());
            }
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }

    private static void Spd_Port_ErrorReceived(Object sender, SerialErrorReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}
```

### Arduino

```
void setup()
{
    // set all pins as inputs (except serial pins)
    init_pins();

    pinMode(ARD_LED, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(ARD_LED, HIGH);

    // Configure serial port
    Serial.begin(115200);
}

int i = 0;
void loop()
{
    int j = Serial.write(0x24);
    if (j)
    {
        digitalWrite(ARD_LED, i == 0 ? HIGH : LOW);
        i = (i + 1) % 2;
    }

    delay(1000);
}
```

Comment: Have you ensured you set both DtrEnable AND RtsEnable to true? http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=110942.0

Comment: In your C# code, I would recommend you create the `SerialPort` object globally, then have a button to `open` and `close` your port.  I would also subscribe to the `DataReceived Event`, It's not good practice to have your program stuck in a endless while loop. [See here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.datareceived%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: @PaulF Thanks - either one works!  Not sure why though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try enabling [DTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable(v=vs.110).aspx) and [RTS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.rtsenable(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
_serialPort.DtrEnable = true;
_serialPort.RtsEnable = true;
```

***EDIT***

According to gregsmi it is working by enabling either DTR or RTS

Comment: This worked!  Actually works if *either* DtrEnable or RtsEnable are set to true...

Comment: @gregsmi thank you for your feedback. Sorry didn't remember exactly - it's been a while

Comment: Arduino does not use these signals.  Not properly initializing SerialPort and then discovering that something random seems to fix the problem is a nasty issue.  It probably will be back.  Handshake is the most typical issue, it is truly random when never assigned.  It has to be None for Arduino.

Comment: @Hans Passant, could you post working code without DTS/RTS for Arduino? I sadly do not have anymore any Arduino with me for testing it out - yes Handshake has to set to None, but this way you simply cannot read from Arduino.

Comment: @HansPassant, can you clarify what you mean by "Arduino does not use these signals"?  My experience above suggests at least the Arduino Micro does depend on them somehow, in fact it won't send otherwise. Note I definitely have written for other models of Arduino (Due?) in the past that do *not* care about these signals - otherwise I would've encountered this problem before...